# Is this an appropriate use for the adapter pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, adapter

I have two representations of an entity in a system.

Representation A is used throughout the system as the modern, preferred implementation.

Representation B is used to cater for quirks in a legacy system.

I would like translation from A to B to occur when persisting the entity.

What pattern of implementation could I use for this?

Might it be correct to implement an "adapter" that encapsulates the translation functionality? Or is there a better term/way?

Comment: Adapters are normally used for adapting interfaces, not whole objects, I think one of the factory patterns might be a better fit

Comment: if it's just for persisting I would say that the repository pattern is a good fit

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to combine adaptor with factory, or just through normal inheritance.

Extract the interface A from the preferred implementation, then implement a wrapper class.

```
public interface A {
  <methods>
}

public class PreferredImplementation implements A {
  <methods>
}

public class AdaptorForOldClass implements A {
  private final OldClass wrapped;

  public AdaptorForOldClass(final OldClass toWrap) {
    this.wrapped = toWrap;
  }

  <methods>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is to Map Class A to B only while persisting it. For this purpose I think you can just use a Data Transfer Object and then your persistent layer can do the mapping from this DTO to Class B. I really can't see the use of Adapter design patterns unless you have much more requirements than you have stated.